# Windows 10 Pro OEM invalid key

Tags: windows-10, oem, clean-install

I'm having problem on activating my Windows 10 Pro on my PC.
Previously I have Windows 7 Ultimate on my PC and decided to upgrade to Windows 10. I bought an OEM Windows 10 Pro in play-asia.com and immediately I received the key. I used the media creation tool to download and create bootable usb drive for it. I choose to create ISO first as Scan Disk USB Drive is not supported for whatever reason so what I did was I used Rufus to create bootable USB using the ISO I downloaded. I manage to install windows 10 on my PC but when I try to activate it always says that my key is not valid. I would like to ask if clean install means everything is that to delete including the partition I made before. When I was in windows 7 I do have 2 partition for my drive and I only deleted the partition where my windows 7 was installed and keep my other partition for backup.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you bought an OEM or volume license key at a retail location via digital download, and it is not legitimate. This is why it will not activate.

> At the moment there are a limited number of sites where you can
>   legally purchase digital downloads of Microsoft software.
>
> With the exception of Product Key Cards (PKC’s) distributed with
>   COA’s, Microsoft does not distribute products keys as standalone
>   products. If you see a listing on an auction site, online classified
>   ad, or other online page advertising product keys for sale, it’s a
>   good indication that the keys are likely stolen or counterfeit.

[Source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/howtotell/Shop.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

seems the volume license for the win10 you downloaded has probably been exhausted

you should contact support with your claim; https://www.play-asia.com/info/helprefund

clean install should not require you remove existing hard disk partitions, only that you install the files to a partition that is 'clean'.

Comment: thanks for your answer... i already contact their team for the possible solution.